# Move semantics and function order evaluation

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, move-semantics, unspecified-behavior

Suppose I have the following:

```
#include <memory>
struct A { int x; };

class B {
  B(int x, std::unique_ptr<A> a);
};

class C : public B {
  C(std::unique_ptr<A> a) : B(a->x, std::move(a)) {}
};
```

If I understand the C++ rules about "unspecified order of function parameters" correctly, this code is unsafe. If the second argument to `B`'s constructor is constructed first using the move constructor, then `a` now contains a `nullptr` and the expression `a->x` will trigger undefined behavior (likely segfault). If the first argument is constructed first, then everything will work as intended.

If this were a normal function call, we could just create a temporary:

```
auto x = a->x
B b{x, std::move(a)};
```

But in the class initialization list we don't have the freedom to create temporary variables.

Suppose I cannot change `B`, is there any possible way to accomplish the above? Namely dereferencing and moving a `unique_ptr` in the same function call expression without creating a temporary?

What if you could change `B`'s constructor but not add new methods such as `setX(int)`? Would that help?

Thank you

Comment: If you can change `B`'s constructor you don't need to do any of this. Just have a single argument, `unique_ptr<A>` and do the copy of `a->x` in the constructor's initialization list.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to change `B`'s interface in such a way to support this specific usage. Initializing `x` with `a->x` might not be a expected thing to do and thus should not require a special case from `B`. It depends on the context, but it might be more natural for a constructor taking only the `unique_ptr` to initialize `x` to some default constant instead of `a->x`. If we change `B` to take the `unique_ptr` by rvalue reference, we give callers more flexibility for free and don't change the interface. I don't see any reason why the `unique_ptr` argument should be passed by value here.

Comment: You're right, there's no downside to passing by rvalue reference here. Another possibility is keeping the existing `B` constructor, and adding an overload that takes only a `unique_ptr<A>`. In that case it's implied `B` will initialize `x` from `a->x`. Which one you choose really depends on the intended use of your class.

Comment: See Scott Meyers' post that this question inspired: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com.au/2014/07/should-move-only-types-ever-be-passed.html

Answer (score 47):

Use list initialization to construct `B`. The elements are then guaranteed to be evaluated from left to right.

```
C(std::unique_ptr<A> a) : B{a->x, std::move(a)} {}
//                         ^                  ^ - braces
```

From *§8.5.4/4 [dcl.init.list]*

> Within the *initializer-list* of a *braced-init-list*, the *initializer-clauses*, including any that result from pack expansions (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear. That is, every value computation and side effect associated with a given *initializer-clause* is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any *initializer-clause* that follows it in the comma-separated list of the *initializer-list*.

Comment: Did not know that rule.  Does that come from C? That is, does struct initialization in C maintain this quality?

Comment: @RyanHaining In case of POD structs, the initialization using braces is aggregate initialization, which has always been part of C++ (inherited from C). C++11 added list initialization (which is what I'm using here), which also encompasses aggregate initialization. I'm pretty sure aggregate initialization has always has a specified order of evaluation from left to right because `struct`, or `class`, members are always initialized in the order they're defined in.

Comment: I'll look at designated initializers in C99, it would make sense that they'd still be evaluated in the order that they're defined, but if the standard specifies "order they appear" I could be wrong.

Comment: @RyanHaining Good point about designated initializers, I don't know what C99 states about those. Anyway, everything I said only applies to C++. It's possible it's also true for C, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: **NOTE**: `gcc` has, for a long time, been [violating the evaluation order](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253) inside *braced-init-list's*; the bug was fixed **2014-07-01** (trunk).

Answer (score 33):

As alternative to Praetorian's answer, you can use constructor delegate:

```
class C : public B {
public:
    C(std::unique_ptr<A> a) :
        C(a->x, std::move(a)) // this move doesn't nullify a.
    {}

private:
    C(int x, std::unique_ptr<A>&& a) :
        B(x, std::move(a)) // this one does, but we already have copied x
    {}
};
```

Comment: Why does the first move not nullify a? Is it because std::move is basically just a cast?

Comment: @ChrisDrew Yes, all you're doing there is binding it to a reference. The actual moving of the internals will be done in `C`'s private constructor's initialization list when the argument for `B`'s constructor is constructed.

Answer (score 11):

Praetorian's suggestion of using list initialization seems to work, but it has a few problems:

1. If the unique_ptr argument comes first, we're out of luck
2. Its way too easy for clients of `B` to accidentally forget to use `{}` instead of `()`. The designers of `B`'s interface has imposed this potential bug on us.

If we could change B, then perhaps one better solution for constructors is to always pass unique_ptr by rvalue reference instead of by value.

```
struct A { int x; };

class B {
  B(std::unique_ptr<A>&& a, int x) : _x(x), _a(std::move(a)) {}
};
```

Now we can safely use std::move().

```
B b(std::move(a), a->x);
B b{std::move(a), a->x};
```

Comment: @Deduplicator: No one's passing `a.get()` (the raw pointer the `unique_ptr` contains)

Comment: @Jarod42:  This is the asker's own answer.

Comment: If we are allowed to change `B`, I would suggest the (pragmatic) solution of adding a constructor to `B` that only takes a `unique_ptr<A>` which sets `x` internally from `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The code contains no undefined behaviour.  This is a common mis-conception that std::move() actually performs a move, it does not.  std::move() simply casts the input to an r-value reference which is a semantic compile time change and has no runtime code.  Therefore in the statement:

```
B(a->x, std::move(a))
```

The state of 'a' is not modified by the std::move() call therefore there is no undefined behaviour regardless of the evaluation ordering.

Comment: Think again. Even though the `move(a)` by itself does not move anything, the initialization of the `B`'s second parameter does move from `a`. If this happens before `a->x` is evaluated, then there is undefined behavior.