# C++11: std::move() call on arguments' list

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Is it safe to operate on object within arguments' list, when there is also std::move() invoked on that object ?

```
void foo(int* raw, std::unique_ptr<int> u)
{
    *raw = 456;
}

std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(123));
foo(p.get(), std::move(p));
```

Will the `raw' pointer in foo() be valid if std::move(p) was evaluated as the first parameter ?

Comment: sure, but will "p.get()" return the pointer to my value=123, if std::move(p) was evaluated first ?

Comment: Considering that the evaluation order of arguments is not specified and can happen in any order, then no this isn't safe. If the `std::move` operation was evaluated first, then `p.get()` will return `nullptr`.

Comment: [Pretty easy to check for yourself](http://ideone.com/smXG2K).

Comment: `std::move` does nothing, so that cannot possibly matter. It's `std::unique_ptr<int>`'s constructor, implicitly called, that's destructive.

Comment: @hvd: but the code seems to crash the program when executed, I think when second argument is evaluated then it also implicitly invokes the unique_ptr<> ctor of parameter, which steals the pointer from `p', doesn't it ?

Comment: @MarcAndreson Exactly. (I did try to cover that in my comment.) I wanted to point it out because if your function had a `std::unique_ptr<int> &&` parameter, there would be absolutely no issue, even though the call would look exactly the same, including the `std::move` part.

Comment: great, then if I had an std::map<int*, unique_ptr<int>>, and I used myMap.emplace(p.get(), std::move(p)) then it should be totally safe, because map<K,T>::emplace gets r-value references? (actually this is my original concern, can I std::move arguments to emplace method)

Comment: @MarcAndreson As far as I can tell, that should be okay, and does not have the problem that the code in your question does have.

Comment: please see edit; iavr points out my fault.

Comment: Related to [move-semantics-and-function-order-evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814696/move-semantics-and-function-order-evaluation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's **NOT** safe. the eval order of argument is *not* specified in standard. So your code *can* be run as:

1. `std::move(p)`.
2. call move constructor of `std::unique_ptr<int>`.
3. `p.get()` (because of 2., this will be `nullptr`.) and pass this parameter.
4. call `foo`.

You have to do like this:

```
int *raw = p.get();
foo(raw, std::move(p));
```

*Notice that your code can work well, because some compilers can compile your code into 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4. However, it doesn't mean code is safe. it's not specified standard >o<*

Comment: But `std::move` doesn't do anything. It's just a type cast.

Comment: @iavr, true, but the `std::unique_ptr<int> u` is created in this mix, and it's part of the unspecified order (so it can happen at any time (between `1.` and `3.` (update `4.`)) before `foo` is called).

Comment: so if foo() would simply std::forward() arguments to other function instead of operating on them, then it would be safe, because before arguments get forwarded, they are evaluated, right ?

Comment: @MarcAndreson Yes, **if the type of the parameter of `foo` is rvalue reference, which is `std::unique_ptr<int> &&**. But I don't suggest it - the easier code is, the better.

Comment: @ikh: it's not hard to find an example of such code: std::map<K,V>::emplace(T&&...) gets r-value references, I wonder what would happen if emplace was inlined by the compiler? will the arguments still be evaluated before entering this inline function? because std::forward is an inline function, so is there still a threat that std::map<K,V>::emplace(k, std::move(k)) is not safe ?

Comment: @MarcAndreson That's no regard, because the parameters of `std::forward` is also rvalue reference >o<

Comment: not sure if I understood you correctly, but if std::map::emplace AND std::forward AND std::pair constructor were ALL inlined by compiler, could this somehow skip the evaluation of parameters before operating on them (i.e. stealing pointer to build map's value-pair prior to evaluating first argument of emplace) ?

Comment: I meant that "foo(p, std::move(p))" results in evaluating parameters (in any order) before entering the function's body, but does the same apply to inline functions? because if not, then even when my function accepted r-value reference (unique_ptr<T>&&) as parameter instead of unique_ptr<T>, I can all in all end up with my original problem when the content is stolen before other parameter's value is calculated, e.g. the unique_ptr<int> inserted to map<int*, unique_ptr<int>> before "int*" was evaluated to be the key of my map in myMap.emplace(p.get(), std::move(p)) call.

Comment: @MarcAndreson Whether it's inline or not, arguments is evaluated before calling. (It seems I haven't got your point yet, because of my poor understanding or poor English skill >o<)

Comment: "Whether it's inline or not, arguments is evaluated before calling" - that fully solves my concern, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Here are answers about argument evaluation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621542/compilers-and-argument-order-of-evaluation-in-c) - In short: **the order is not specified in standard and may be different per platform, compiler and calling convention.**

But I wanted to test it so here are results for Cygwin GCC:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
void print(int* p) {
    cout << (p == nullptr ? "null" : "valid") << endl; }
void foo(int* p, unique_ptr<int> u) {
    print(p); }
void bar(unique_ptr<int> u, int* p) {
    print(p); }
__stdcall void foo2(int* p, unique_ptr<int> u) {
    print(p); }
__stdcall void bar2(unique_ptr<int> u, int* p) {
    print(p); }
__cdecl void foo3(int* p, unique_ptr<int> u) {
    print(p); }
__cdecl void bar3(unique_ptr<int> u, int* p) {
    print(p); }
int main() {
    unique_ptr<int> p(new int(1)), q(new int(2));
    foo(p.get(), move(p)); bar(move(q), q.get());
    unique_ptr<int> p2(new int(1)), q2(new int(2));
    foo2(p2.get(), move(p2)); bar2(move(q2), q2.get());
    unique_ptr<int> p3(new int(1)), q3(new int(2));
    foo3(p3.get(), move(p3)); bar3(move(q3), q3.get());
}
```

***Output:***

```
null
valid
null
valid
null
valid
```

Surprise is that I could not force it to change the order even when I used `__stdcall` and `__cdecl`.

**EDIT**: Same test with **MSVC 2012** (__stdcall/__cdecl moved before names), **same result**!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `std::move()` on arguments is perfectly safe.

What is not safe is tripping yourself up by writing to a raw pointer that was managed by an object that has relinquished the pointer's memory to the free store.

Comment: this is just an example to illustrate the problem

Comment: @Marc What I mean is there is nothing inherently unsafe about using `std::move()`. What your example is doing is undefined behaviour. Not because you used `std::move()` but because your example relies on the order of execution of two functions whose order of execution is undefined.