# Is std::move safe in an arguments list when the argument is forwarded, not move constructed?

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics, string-view

Trying to provide a solution to [std::string_view and std::string in std::unordered_set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51749081/364696), I'm playing around with replacing `std::unordered_set<std::string>` with `std::unordered_map<std::string_view, std::unique_ptr<std::string>>` (the value is `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` because the small string optimization would mean that the address of the `string`'s underlying data will not always be transferred as a result of `std::move`).

My original test code, that seems to work, is (omitting headers):

```
using namespace std::literals;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string_view, std::unique_ptr<std::string>> mymap;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        auto to_insert = std::make_unique<std::string>(argv[i]);
        
        mymap.try_emplace(*to_insert, std::move(to_insert));
    }

    for (auto&& entry : mymap) {
        std::cout << entry.first << ": " << entry.second << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "\"this\" in map? " << (mymap.count("this") == 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "\"this\"s in map? " << (mymap.count("this"s) == 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "\"this\"sv in map? " << (mymap.count("this"sv) == 1) << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile with `g++` 7.2.0, compile line is `g++ -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -flto -pedantic test_string_view.cpp -o test_string_view` receiving no warnings of any kind, then run, getting the following output:

```
$ test_string_view this is a test this is a second test
second: second
test: test
a: a
this: this
is: is
"this" in map? true
"this"s in map? true
"this"sv in map? true
```

which is what I expected.

My main concern here is whether:

```
        mymap.try_emplace(*to_insert, std::move(to_insert));
```

has defined behavior. The `*to_insert` relies on `to_insert` not being emptied (by move constructing the `std::unique_ptr` stored in the map) until after the `string_view` is constructed. The two definitions of `try_emplace` that would be considered are:

```
try_emplace(const key_type& k, Args&&... args);
```

and

```
try_emplace(key_type&& k, Args&&... args);
```

I'm not sure which would be chosen, but either way, it seems like `key_type` would be constructed as part of calling `try_emplace`, while the arguments to make the `mapped_type` (the "value", though maps seem to use `value_type` to refer to the combined key/value `pair`) are forwarded along, and not used immediately, which makes the code defined. Am I correct in this interpretation, or is this undefined behavior?

My concern is that other, similar constructions that seem definitely undefined still seem to work, e.g.:

```
mymap.insert(std::make_pair<std::string_view,
                            std::unique_ptr<std::string>>(*to_insert,
                                                          std::move(to_insert)));
```

produces the expected output, while similar constructs like:

```
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(std::string_view(*to_insert),
                            std::unique_ptr<std::string>(std::move(to_insert))));
```

trigger a `Segmentation fault` at runtime, despite none of them raising warnings of any kind, and both constructs seemingly equally unsequenced (unsequenced implicit conversions in the working `insert`, unsequenced explicit conversion in the segfaulting `insert`), so I don't want to say "`try_emplace` worked for me, so it's okay."

Note that while this question is similar to [C++11: std::move() call on arguments' list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25180339/364696), it's not quite a duplicate (it's what presumably makes the `std::make_pair` here unsafe, but not necessarily applicable to `try_emplace`'s forwarding based behavior); in that question, the function receiving the arguments receives `std::unique_ptr`, triggering construction immediately, while `try_emplace` is receiving arguments for forwarding, not `std::unique_ptr`, so while the `std::move` has "occurred" (but done nothing yet), I *think* we're safe since the `std::unique_ptr` is constructed "later".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your call to `try_emplace` is perfectly safe. `std::move` actually doesn't move anything, it just casts the passed variable to an xvalue. No matter what order the arguments are initialized, nothing will ever be moved because the parameters are all references. References bind directly to objects, they do not call any constructors.

If you look at your second snippet, you'll see that `std::make_pair` also takes its parameters by reference, so in that case too a move will not be made except in the constructor body.

Your third snippet however does have the problem of UB. The difference is subtle, but if the arguments of `make_pair` are evaluated left-to-right, then a temporary `std::unique_ptr` object will get initialized with the moved from value of `to_insert`. This means that now, `to_insert` is null because a move actually happened because you are explicitly constructing an object that actually performs the move.

Comment: While this is true, I'd still recommend being very careful with it. You have to know the signature of the function you're calling to know that all its arguments are references in order for this to be safe. And if the author later changes an argument to be by value, this would no longer be safe. Knowing nothing about the signature of a function, `foo.frobnicate(*bar, std::move(bar))` raises a red flag.

Comment: The second snippet is still using `std::make_pair`, not the `std::pair` constructor directly, it's just explicitly specifying the templated types (triggering implicit construction), rather than explicitly constructing, then passing. Shouldn't that be equally unsafe? Even receiving by universal reference, it would have to construct the correct types, it's just moving the time of construction to "just before call time" to "at call time", but either one is still unsequenced, right? There isn't a sequence point between "loading" arguments and converting them to the required types, is there?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oops; It doesn't make a difference though. Yes, the arguments needs to be initialized, but because they are references, there is no move happening if you ignore the body. Indeed, if you replace `make_pair` by a function with the same signature but empty body, no move will be made. There are no more sequence points, but yes, each argument is initialized and then the next one is, ... There is no interleaving or such.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Ah, I see my mistake. In general, when a conversion is required, receiving by reference would still require construction. But in this case, only the first argument requires conversion, not the second; it constructs the `string_view` from `*to_insert` immediately, but just passes along the `xvalue` reference to `to_insert` without emptying it; the `unique_ptr` is already the correct type. Much like `try_emplace`, the `string_view` *is* created immediately as part of calling `std::make_pair`, while the `unique_ptr` isn't move constructed until later. Thanks!