# How can I extract a raw pointer from a unique_ptr before moving it into my base class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, unique-ptr

I have a very specific need to access functionality specific to a derived class of which I get an instance in a `unique_ptr` at construction of the containing class. This containing class must then move the `unique_ptr` upcast to its base class to the containing class' base class constructor, where it is finally `move`d for ownership in that base containing class. Some code should help:

```
class MemberBase {};
class MemberDerived : public MemberBase { /*some public stuff not in MemberBase*/ };

class MainBase {
  std::unique_ptr<MemberBase> member_;

 public:
  MainBase(std::unique_ptr<MemberBase> member) : member_(std::move(member)) {}
};

class MainDerived : public MainBase {
  MemberDerived* member_derived_;
  // This class proceeds to use MemberDerived-only functions

 public:
  // How to write the initialization list below?
  MainDerived(std::unique_ptr<MemberDerived> member)
    : MainBase(std::move(member)), member_derived_(member.get() /*nullptr!!*/) {}
};
```

Ignoring the question of overall class design (I'm aware that the coupling to `MemberDerived`-specific functions in `MainDerived` is not ideal; this is inherited code that cannot be altered without major refactor), how can I snag the raw pointer before forwarding the `unique_ptr` to `MainBase`?

Find below some ideas I have thought of and why I do not think they are great.

1. Downcast protected accessor:

```
// Add this method to the protected section of MainBase:
MemberBase* MainBase::get_member() { return member_.get(); }

// Then downcast in MainDerived's c'tor
MainDerived::MainDerived(std::unique_ptr<MemberDerived> member)
  : MainBase(std::move(member)), member_derived_(dynamic_cast<MemberDerived*>(get_member())) {}
```

This should work but uses `dynamic_cast` (major downside in and of itself) and of course if someone changes the type passed to the c'tor to something not derived from `MemberDerived` it will break with no help from the compiler.

2. Pass in the pointer twice:

```
// member and member_derived must point to the same object!
MainDerived::MainDerived(std::unique_ptr<MemberDerived> member, MemberDerived* member_derived)
  : MainBase(std::move(member)), member_derived_(member_derived) {}
```

Besides making for a pretty ugly c'tor signature it would be pretty easy for the user to pass a different pointer for both arguments or do the `move` before calling `get`. Furthermore the user is now forced to create a local variable to pass it into both places. Did I mention it's ugly?

3. Flip initialization order with helper function trickery:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> ExtractPointer(std::unique_ptr<T> p, T** target) {
  *target = p.get();
  return std::move(p);
}

MainDerived::MainDerived(std::unique_ptr<MemberDerived> member)
  : MainBase(ExtractPointer(std::move(member), &member_derived_)) {}
```

Now I was actually a bit surprised that this did not produce any warnings/errors (gcc 5.4.0 with `-Wall`). Part of me likes this as it seems safe in the sense that it is hard to break but the circuitous initialization of `member_derived_` gives me minor chills.

Comment: Related to [move-semantics-and-function-order-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814696/move-semantics-and-function-order-evaluation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second solution is halfway there. Note that the constructor does not need to be `public`. You can make the 2-argument one `private` and write a 1-argument `public` constructor that delegates to it.

```
class MainDerived : public MainBase {
  MemberDerived* member_derived_;

  MainDerived(std::unique_ptr<MemberDerived> &member, MemberDerived *member_derived)
    : MainBase(std::move(member)), member_derived_(member_derived) { }

 public:
  MainDerived(std::unique_ptr<MemberDerived> member)
    : MainDerived(member, member.get()) { }
};
```

`member` must be taken by reference in the `private` constructor, as the ordering of the evaluations of the arguments of a function call is unspecified. Thus, you can't safely move `member` from the `public` constructor into an argument of the `private` one, as then the ordering of the move and the `get()` would be unspecified, but we need `get()` to happen before the move. The easiest fix is for the `private` constructor to take the `member` by reference, which does not mutate it. (You can also use `{}` instead of `()` to enforce the order of evaluation, but making your code depend on such a delicate construct is not a good idea.)

Comment: You don't actually have to release; the delegated constructor can just have 2 arguments.

Comment: @o11c No, wait, I don't think that works. In order to have two arguments, you need to move the `unique_ptr` into one of them. But the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified, so I don't think there's a guarantee that the call to extract the raw pointer will see the original `unique_ptr` and not the empty one. There's another reason you may want to use 2 arguments, though...

Comment: @HTNW I think left-to-right sequencing is guaranteed if you use list-initialization, i.e. `MainDerived{..., ...}` instead of `MainDerived(..., ...)`. Whether you want to make code-correctness depend on that detail is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that the pointer is to a `MemberDerived`, you don't need `dynamic_cast`. A `static_cast` will do.

If you are worried about making a mistake in the types when something is changed, then just refer to the element type:

```
MainDerived(std::unique_ptr<MemberDerived> member)
  : MainBase(std::move(member))
  , member_derived_(static_cast<decltype(member)::element_type*>(member_.get())) 
{}
```

As you mentioned this requires `member_` to be `protected` or a `protected` getter to exist.

As far as I can tell there is no case where this can lead to undefined behavior, except if someone passes a `std::unique_ptr` that doesn't actually point to an object of type identical to or derived from it's `element_type`, in which case use of this `std::unique_ptr` would itself be unsafe, because it would cause undefined behavior if the instance was destroyed without prior move.

---

As for your 3. suggested method:

I think this is technically allowed in C++17, because `member_derived_` has vacuous initialization, so its lifetime begins when its storage is allocated, not when its initialization finishes.

But the current C++20 draft removes this exception, so that `member_derived_`'s lifetime will start only after its vacuous initialization, making this use undefined behavior.

Comment: tks for 2 useful callouts